# Update custom user profile properties - Powershell - SharePoint

Tags: powershell, user-profile, custom, user-profile-property

Having problem updating custom user profile properties. Anyone with the same problem, code below:

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::Loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.Office.Server");            
$site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("$ProfilFullURL");            
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site;            
$site.Dispose();            
$upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext);

function Update-UserProfileProperty ($property, $excelProperty)
{
Write-Host "Setting property $property : " -NoNewline
Try
{       
    $userProfile["$property"].Value = $excelProperty;            
    $userProfile.Commit()
    Write-Host "$excelProperty" -ForegroundColor Green
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
    Write-Host "Error" -ForegroundColor Red
}
}

Foreach ($user in $userobjects) 
{
    $userProfile = Get-UserProfileProperties $user
}

function Get-UserProfileProperties ($user)
{ 
   $userName = $user.SM_LoginName
Write-Host "$userName : Finding user profile ..." -NoNewline
Try
{       
     $userProfile = $upm.GetUserProfile("$userName")
     Write-Host "Found" -ForegroundColor Green
     UserProfileProperty $user

}
Catch [system.exception]
{
    Write-Host "Not found" -ForegroundColor Red
    return
}
return $userProfile
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to add migrate data from a excel spreadsheet into the custom user profile property. The user and property exist!

The code works with standard properties like FirstName etc.

**UPDATE**
The error I got is

The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $userProfile[$property].Value = $excelProperty
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Got this error ONLY on custom user properties

Comment: "Having problem" / "Anyone with the same problem": What kind of problem do you have exactly? An exception (at which line?) or the property simlpy was not updated?

Comment: The problem is that standard user properties can be set by the code. But custom user properties do not!

Comment: Do you have an error (catched exception in code)? If you dump out the profile properties ($upm.Properties | % { $_.Name }), is the name you use in the list?

Comment: Yes the property is listed .. But it dosent want to be set..

Comment: But does it seem correct? Have you tried to set a custom user property like I've done ?

Comment: Yes, it should work. Personally, I don't use the syntax $userProfile["$property"], instead without the quotes like $userProfile[$property], but it should not make a difference, AFAIK. What I don't see in your code, where the $userProfile variable in the Update-UserProfileProperty method was defined. What is the type of your custom propety? String / date / integer, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should work. Personally, I don't use the syntax $userProfile["$property"], instead without the quotes like $userProfile[$property], but it should not make a difference, AFAIK. What I don't see in your code, where the $userProfile variable in the Update-UserProfileProperty method was defined. What is the type of your custom property? String / date / integer, etc.?

Please, ensure that you do use the right data type!